# Does batch's parentheses have a limit to how much output it can hold?

Tags: command-line, batch, memory-limit

I have been using this batch code: https://github.com/ITCMD/in2batch and it outputs something that looks like this:

```
(
echo gfgqebfwrwe
echo grgrgehrg4wer
echo htrehteertrehrt
+12,000 more lines of that
) >>outputfile.txt
```

([here is the actual file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ITCMD/ITCMD-STORAGE/master/tempShare.bat))
However the program just closes. It stops on line 10,692 with `echo`. There are no special characters on the line it stops on, or the line after. Does batch have a limit to how many lines of output can be inside a single `()`?

Comment: Sounds like some of `echo …` line contains an unescaped closing parenthesis `)`. Check presence of any _`cmd`-poisonous_ character like `&` , `<`, `>`, `^` or `|` as well.

Comment: So now, it's not even putting any into a file. It is just echoing it all onto the screen.  It stops on line `10692` (`echo AAAAAAAAAAD/////JDhHACAFkxkCAAAA0OFHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`) then crashes. the output file is not even created. Here is what I am running: https://github.com/ITCMD/ITCMD-STORAGE/raw/master/tempShare.bat

Comment: You are right. _Event Viewer_ shows `Exception Code 0xc00000fd` which means **Stack overflow**. As a workaround, divide parenthesized block to parts of less `echo` lines each (e.g. 2000 = very gingerly limit).

Comment: @JosefZ thanks. I can just group each line in parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, running unadjusted [tempShare.bat](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ITCMD/ITCMD-STORAGE/master/tempShare.bat) led to `cmd` crash with application error and exception code `0xc00000fd` which means **Stack overflow** (oddly enough - it stopped at different line if run repeatedly e.g. `10692`/`10711`/`10707` so I can't give any *exact* answer about count limit of lines in parentheses).

Fortunately, no error happens redirecting output from a [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop.

Hence, following slight changes to the original script led to desired effect. Adjusted script parses itself in a simple `for /F` loop and performs only `echo` commands between `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and `END CERTIFICATE` inclusively (see lines `5..16)`:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableextensions
if exist "7za.exe" goto :10897117303211127370517328436 
echo creating file . . .
set "_out="
(
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in ("%~f0") do (
  if "%%~G"=="echo -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" set "_out=yes"
  if defined _out %%~G
  if "%%~G"=="echo -----END CERTIFICATE-----" set "_out="
)
)>temp.txt
certutil -v -decode "temp.txt" "7za.exe"
REM  >nul 
REM del /f /q "temp.txt"
goto :10897117303211127370517328436
(
echo -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
echo TVqQAAMAAAAEAAAA//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+AAAAA4fug4AtAnNIbgBTM0hVGhpcyBwcm9ncmFtIGNhbm5v
… truncated 12000+ lines of that …
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
echo -----END CERTIFICATE-----
)>temp.txt
certutil -v -decode "temp.txt" "7za.exe" >nul
del /f /q "temp.txt" 
:10897117303211127370517328436
pause
```

**Output**:

```
d:\bat> erase 7za.exe 2>nul

d:\bat> D:\bat\SU\tempShare.bat
creating file . . .
Input Length = 808252
Output Length = 587776
CertUtil: -decode command completed successfully.
Press any key to continue . . .

d:\bat> 7za.exe -?

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Usage: 7za <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
       [<@listfiles...>]

… (truncated) …
```

The  following `tempShareExitLoop.bat` does the same but stops reading itself after reaching the `END CERTIFICATE` line. Important: insert the `:OutCertificate` procedure somewhere (immediately) below some `goto :eof` in your code.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableextensions
if exist "7za.exe" goto :10897117303211127370517328436 
echo creating file . . .
>temp.txt call :OutCertificate
certutil -v -decode "temp.txt" "7za.exe"
REM  >nul 
REM del /f /q "temp.txt"
goto :10897117303211127370517328436
(
echo -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
echo TVqQAAMAAAAEAAAA//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+AAAAA4fug4AtAnNIbgBTM0hVGhpcyBwcm9ncmFtIGNhbm5v
… truncated 12000+ lines of that …
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
echo -----END CERTIFICATE-----
)>temp.txt
certutil -v -decode "temp.txt" "7za.exe" >nul
del /f /q "temp.txt" 
:10897117303211127370517328436
pause
goto :eof 

:OutCertificate
set "_out="
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in ("%~f0") do (
  if "%%~G"=="echo -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" set "_out=yes"
  if defined _out %%~G
  if "%%~G"=="echo -----END CERTIFICATE-----" goto :eof
)
goto :eof
```

Comment: I modified your script so it looks for `REM ARandomNumber` instead of `echo -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` so it can have multiple in the same script.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `) was unexpected at this time.`. Can you take a look at my script and see if I have it right? https://github.com/ITCMD/ITCMD-STORAGE/blob/master/tempShare.bat

Comment: @MarkDeven [**Never** use `:label` nor `:: label-like comment` inside a command block enclosed in `()` parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404). Just remove the `:break …` line and keep `set "_out="` instead of ´goto break…´.

Comment: But I’ll probably have two or three of those 30,000 line things in the file, won’t that slow it down if it has to skip over the rest?

Comment: @MarkDeven answer updated.

Comment: mind me asking why you use `setlocal enableextensions` and where I could put an `endlocal`? I assume after the `)` of `:OutCertificate`?

Comment: Also what are the two REM lines for? And I can remove the parentheses around the certutil stuff right?

Comment: @MarkDeven `REM`s are there merely to retain the original code as wide as possible. And yes, you can remove the parentheses around the certutil stuff as well as all the stuff between `)>temp.txt` (incl.) and the `:10897117303211127370517328436` label (excl.)

Comment: Here's the final project: https://github.com/ITCMD/In2Batch Thanks for your help.

Comment: *it stopped at different line if run repeatedly* because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows). The stack is big so many pages will be allocated for it, and the start of stack is always **align to the page size** (4KB by default), which makes the last bits of the address always zero. To make the real address harder to guess [an offset of half the page size (2KB) will be added](https://www.symantec.com/avcenter/reference/Address_Space_Layout_Randomization.pdf), limiting the real remaining stack space for the program